# marmap separate palette for topography above sea level

Tags: r, colors, plot

When using the package `marmap`, is it possible to use separate palettes for topography above sea level and for bathymetry below sea level? I would like to use a green palette to show the mountains on an Island, and then the blues for the bathymetry. In this example I used the Atlantic dataset, which has some land topographic data in the top left of the plot.

```
library(marmap)

##load some data
data(nw.atlantic)
atl <- as.bathy(nw.atlantic)

##create two palettes, one for above sea level (greens), one for below (blues)
blues <- colorRampPalette(c("purple", "darkblue", "blue", "cadetblue1",
                            "lightblue"))
greens <- colorRampPalette(c("#00CC00", "#33CC33", "#009900", "#006633"))

##plot the bathymetry, some land topography is seen in the top left corner
plot.bathy(atl, land=T, image=T, bpal=blues(100), n=50) 

##try setting the palettes by deep and shallow... no luck
plot.bathy(atl, land=T, image=T, bpal=c(blues(100), greens(100)), 
           deep=c(0, -7000), shallow=c(0, 2000), n=50)
```

Comment: Perhaps if you provide `breaks`, e.g. something like: `plot.bathy(atl, land=T, image=T, bpal=c(blues(63), greens(10)), n=10, breaks=c(seq(-6228, 0, 100), seq(0, 1007, 100)))`. (Note in `?plot.bathy` that you can pass arguments accepted by `image` - see `?image`.)

Comment: r question #56000! congratulations james

Comment: Thanks, that works fine jbaums. Just need a little tweaking of breaks, as the actual dataset has a different range of bathymetry/topography to the example.

Answer (score 0):

With marmap v0.8 (available on CRAN since june), the bpal argument of plot.bathy now accepts a list of vectors, each containing boundaries for depth/altitude slices and color names/codes. See the last example of `plot.bathy()` which does exactly what you need. Using your custom palettes, you could just type:

```
plot(atl, land = TRUE, n = 50, lwd = 0.1, image = TRUE, 
     bpal = list(c(min(atl), 0, blues(100)),
                 c(0, max(atl), greens(100))))

# Add coastline
plot(atl, deep=0, shallow=0, step=0, add=TRUE, lwd=.7)
```